# Unable to use WFFM using Sitecore MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, sitecore, sitecore7.2, web-forms-for-marketers

We are trying to use WFFM using MVC implementation.

Sitecore : 7.2

MVC: 5

WFFM version: 2.4.0

We have tried to implement WFFM using MVC from this link https://github.com/PetersonDave/RazorViewsForMarketers

We are stuck on below steps:

Add a Razor Views for Marketers rendering to the presentation details of an item.

I am unable to refer Razor view control.: refer below screenshot.
[image]

Additionally, when we try to access item: Razor view for Marketer under Razor Views(Under rendering). we are getting below error.
[image]

Please provide your inputs for resolving this error.

Link of original SDN: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/275

Answer (score 0):

What specific version of WFFM are you using? 2.4 rev 140923 added direct support for MVC-based solutions so you could skip that GitHub code.

The MVC controller rendering is installed at `/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Mvc Form`.

Comment: Web Forms for Marketers 2.4 rev. 140923 is already installed on my instance. Even though i am not able to render WFFM form.